# Develop nodejs with visual studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, node.js, editor

Is it possible to develop NodeJS applications with VS2010. I'm talking plain ol' Javascript, not Azure or any fancy stuff like that. I just want to use VS2010 as the Javascript editor as I'm from .NET background and I'm very comfortable with it.

If I can, then please tell me how to configure VS2010 to be able to code NodeJS applications.

Answer (score 39):

Sorry, new users aren't allowed to post images.

I can read English,but I can't write in English .So ,just this...囧

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFyWV.jpg
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFyWV.jpg]

Comment: I went to edit this answer and clean things up, but somehow it's perfect the way it is.

Comment: Great :) I did a simple project which starts another application while running. But suddenly I thought it is a big task to achieve this. Kudos brother :)

Comment: There's good description with a bit more detail at: http://www.seesharprun.net/leveraging-visual-studio-2012-for-node.js-development

Comment: I dont understand the picture and all options.  It could be very useful if someone could add a screenshot in English.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to use Visual Studio as a text editor, you can do that to edit Node apps. Use **File** > **Open Website** to open the folder that your Node application is in.

You can then open any *.js file and edit it using Visual Studio's text editor.

If you want to try some experimental Intellisense support, check out [node-vsdoc](https://github.com/kinogam/node-vsdoc). You'll have to add the `nd/node-vsdoc.js` file to your project and then reference it like this:

```
/// <reference path="node-vsdoc.js" />
```

Here's an example: https://github.com/kinogam/node-vsdoc/blob/master/nd/vsdoc-test.js

Comment: Thanks Rohan. But I read this [kinogam](http://www.kinogam.com/?p=330) article. I understood everything except for the part that what VS2010 project template he is using to create the new project for node.

Comment: There's no need to use a project template. Use Create Website and create an empty website. Do this even if your Node project will not be a website.

Comment: That said, based on your comments, you really seem to be seeing everything through the prism of Visual Studio. For a Node app, VS won't help much. You might want to try forgetting VS for this project and just using a simple text editor. I think doing so really helps you grow as a developer.

Comment: I more thing Rohan. I wanted to use [RailwayJS](http://railwayjs.com/) MVC framework for nodejs. Can you please give me a total tutorial so that I can run even run node as external command from VS2010 and also get intellisense for development. I really want to learn this stuff. Thanks Anyway. You have guided me a lot.

Comment: Why I'm stressing on VS2010 is because of the fact, someday answered this question on SO - [Best JavaScript editor or IDE with IntelliSense and debugging (possibly)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925219/best-javascript-editor-or-ide-with-intellisense-and-debugging-possibly).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with RailwayJS so I can't really do that. Maybe try asking a separate question about it? Configuring VS to run a new set of external commands can be a real pain. I'd recommend just using the command line as it will save you tons of time and trouble.

Answer (score 3):

I was using VS for Node development and it was just a very poor experience.  That said, simply create an Empty Website project.  Which is about as empty as a project can be in VS... personally, I wish VS had support for a "non-compiled" or "script" project, to hold misc files, or outside scripts that aren't the purview of VS.  That aside you may want to try out the [typescript plugins for VS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790), as they add a lot of useful intellisense support, for what it's worth.

That said, you may want to give another editor a chance, if you don't need integrated source control you might want to look at [WebMatrix2](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) (free) from MS, there's a plugin that makes node-inspector debugging transparent.  Personally, I've been using [JetBrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) (not too pricey) and loving it.

Answer (score 1):

To get vsdoc.js intelisense going in vs 2008 you need a microsoft patch:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2008/11/07/hotfix-to-enable-vsdoc-js-intellisense-doc-files-is-now-available.aspx

Then follow Rohan's answer to get the rest going

Answer (score 1):

A couple of days ago Microsoft released official tools for Node JS. These tools are huge improvement over the other hacky solutions I've tried to pull off with Visual Studio.

http://techcrunch.com/2013/11/21/microsoft-launches-node-js-tools-for-visual-studio

I've yet to find a VS 2010 version of these tools. Currently, it only supports VS 2012 and VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a uservoice request for this:

[node.js template in visual studio to easy start working on node.js](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2845795-node-js-template-in-visual-studio-to-easy-start-wo)