# how to run node app on iisnode in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, node.js, iisnode

I've managed to run a node app using node.js but i need to run that app on my asp application. hence, i've installed iisnode! but sadly there is no complete documentation on how to run node apps in using iisnode ! so can you help me out and guide me on how to use iisnode to run node apps in visual studio ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: This SO response should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108686/develop-nodejs-with-visual-studio-2010. You may also want to check out the Node.js Tools for Visual Studio (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/885a8a68-e38b-4e6a-b96d-083d5572b645).

Comment: @mongermd I've read that, but is that going to help with running it in visual studio under IIS ? because i thought that will only help with developing it in VS environment!

Comment: @pouria did you manage to find a way to work in Visual Studio with iisnode? I'm used to run my node apps on webmatrix, so that's the default there, but it's hard to migrate it to VS. Cheers

Comment: @AndréLucas Unfortunately it got complicated and due to lack of time I switched to a .net based framework by XSocket.